# Can't add Date in Db

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetime

I'm trying to add Dates into a database using `MySqlCommand`, but the date isn't added correctly. Let me explain. I get the the actual Date like this:

```
Dim book_datetime = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

As you can see I parse the Date  in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`
and it's all working well, but when I perform the insert in my db I get this:

> 2015-12-15

instead of this

> 2015-12-15 11:48:30

This is my code that peform the insert:

```
query = "INSERT INTO setting (book_datetime)
         VALUES(@book_datetimep)"

MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, dbCon)

MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@book_datetimep", book_datetime)
```

My Database `book_datetime` contains a `Date` field. What is wrong? The `book_datetime` is filled correctly after I parse it but when it gets inserted in the DB I get another format. I saw that if I change the field from `Date` to `Text` I get the correct format, but why?

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you just pass the `DateTime` instance to the parameter (`Date.Now`) instead of converting it to a `string`?

Comment: @Amalea is correct, but you should avoid AddWithValue in particular with dates. MySql is gracious enough to try to understand your string as a date but it is better to specify exactly what your parameter is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.
>
> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Use `DATETIME` as your field type instead of `DATE` and the time portion of your date won't be truncated on insert.

Comment: Infact, you're right. Now working well. Thank you for explain this. Have a good day :)